# How do you set a callback on timeout for the node.js request library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request

With node's http library this would look something like

```
var request = http.request(options);
request.setTimeout(milliseconds, callback);
```

However, I'm using the wrapper library [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and don't see a way to add a callback on timeout.

I'm creating an API endpoint to make an http request and expose that data, and I would like to be able to render a null result if the request times out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific timeout callback. It will be called back as an error; then you have to distinguish it from other errors.

```
request({
  timeout: 2000,
  url: 'http://timeout.example.org/'
}).on('error', function(err) {
  if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
    console.log("Timeout!");
  }
});
```